# Determine the order of xml mixed content in derived class

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I have the schema like this :

```
<xsd:complexType name="ContentType" mixed="true">
      <xsd:annotation>
         <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[ 
            The content type is a broad base type allowing any content.
         ]]></xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:complexContent>
         <xsd:extension base="BaseContentType">
            <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="lax"
               />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="orientation" type="OrientationEnum" use="optional"
               default="portrait">
               <xsd:annotation>
                  <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
                  The @orientation attribute is used to specify a "landscape" 
                  orientation for the published form. This is primarily used
                  for schedules or for tables.                  
                  ]]></xsd:documentation>
               </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:attribute>
         </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:complexContent>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

I use xjc command line tool to generate the Java classes from the above schema and the classes are generated as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseContentType {

    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected String id;
```

and

```
public class ContentType
    extends BaseContentType
{

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @OverrideAnnotationOf
    protected List<Object> contentOverrideForContentType;
```

When I unmarshall, all the nested xml elements get populated in the List `contentOverrideForContentType` of the `ContentType` object and all the text elements get populated in the List `content` of `BaseContentType`.

How do I determine the order of the text elements with respect to the nested elements and construct the entire text?

I am trying to get the entire text within the `ContentType` for which I have to look at top level text and the text of all the nested tags and combine them all(here is where I need to know the order). Is there a better way to just extract all the text from `ContentType`?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752520/xjc-not-generating-corresponding-class-member-for-xsdany) question.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a propOrder on the specific jaxB class you can specify the order that objects will appear in the xml

```
e.g. 
@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "firstObjectName",
        "fsecondObjectName"
    })
```

note: when using a propOrder all elements in the object must be added to the propOrder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that the elements will be ordered following the order in which the elements had been added to the list ... this is assuming you are using an ordered list (`List`, `ArrayList`...)